# Django how to add a Group model field

Tags: django

i want add a description filed to Group，
how to do it?
edit source code?

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=80, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(_('description'), max_length=180, 
        null=True, blank=True)  # add 
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        Permission,
        verbose_name=_('permissions'),
        blank=True,
    )

    objects = GroupManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('group')
        verbose_name_plural = _('groups')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.name,)
```

and have other way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using this in your `models.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

Group.add_to_class('description', models.CharField(max_length=180,null=True, blank=True))
```

Comment: Careful, it will create a migration in the django site-packages location, i.e. not in your codebase.